# Put a back cover at the end of the PDF (latex, Rmarkdown)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown

I have a Rmarkdown program (latex and R code) that creates pages and tables. This creates a PDF document that I print out as a booklet.  I have created a final page with an image. I would like this page to always be printed on the back cover when I print the PDF as a booklet.
If the final page is on page 4, 8, 12, 16, it's ok.
But if it is on page 3 or 7 for example, I would have to add a page before.
If it is on page 2 or 6, I have to add 2 more.
And so on.
I know the number of the page just before the final pagethanks to \pageref{XXX}.  But I don't know how to use it in a condition to know if I should add pages before my final page.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you make a [mre] to give use something to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
---
title: "Title"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
 - \ExplSyntaxOn \newcommand{\foo}[2]{\int_mod:nn{#1}{#2}} \ExplSyntaxOff
 - \AtEndDocument{ \clearpage \ifnum\foo{\thepage}{4}=3 \mbox{}\clearpage \fi \ifnum\foo{\thepage}{4}=2 \mbox{}\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage \fi  \ifnum\foo{\thepage}{4}=1 \mbox{}\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage \fi \includegraphics{example-image-duck} }
---

test
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! It totally answers my problem! Thank you so much!